# How to convert pdf to base64 in Azure

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I want to convert pdf file to base64 so I can view it on my power BI. I have tried javascript inline in Logic app but it need integration account that could increase my bill. Is there any ideas to convert pdf to base64 in azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your pdf stored. If you didn't store it in azure blob storage, I think you can store it in blob storage. Then we can get the pdf from blob storage in logic app like below:
[image]

After running the logic app, it will get `$content` in base64.
[image]

**By the way:**

If you do it with javascript inline, you can just create an integration account in free tier.
[image]

After add the integration account to your logic app, you need to wait a few minutes. If you run the logic app immediately, it may show the error message `The integration account 'xxxxxxxxx' is still being provisioned. Please try again later.`
[image]

Comment: Get blob content its really help to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Irwan Or are there any unresolved issues in your case ?

Comment: I was strugling to store the content in my azure sql database, because there is a limit on tabular PBI that allowed 30.000 characters only. Any ideas to store the content into some columns in azure sql database? thanks

Comment: Hi @Irwan Could you please create another post on stack overflow ? I'm not familiar with PBI and sql database, but I will try to take a look on the new post tomorrow(because I will be off work soon).